# generating java stubs from WADL

Tags: java, service, wadl

Is there any tool that can generate java stubs from a WADL file.

or is there any plugin for eclipse/netbeans that can generate stubs from a WADL file.

thanks

vicky

Answer (score 0):

wadl2java tool - http://wadl.java.net/wadl2java.html
It has command line tool and ant target to generate stubs from wadl.
Didn't use it myself yet but am probably going to for my next project.

Comment: This tool is nice, but it appears to not support Basic authentication for REST requests

Answer (score 0):

Try this project: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-description.html

The project is probably still in early stage.  Notice following errors:

- Basic Example at its home page contains two errors

  - "tns:thechapter" is not defined.
  - Need to define type for "id" param for /bookstore/{id}
- If you use its Maven plugin, use 2.4.2 instead of 2.4.1.

I am able to generate Jersey controller skeleton after fixing these errors.